# jquery Hide table row if td has no text

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide

I am trying to hide table row if that rows td has no text inside it. How to do that. 
So far i tried is [at fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chandrashekarthota/v2LAp/1/)

Javascript:

```
$('#tblNodes > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
    if ($td.text() == '') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="tblNodes" border=1 width=100%>
    <tr>
        <td class="nodeData"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nodeData">abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nodeData"></td>
        <tr>
            <td class="nodeData"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="nodeData">abc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="nodeData"></td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('#tblNodes > tbody  > tr').has('td:empty').hide()
```

or

```
$('#tblNodes > tbody  > tr td:empty').parent().hide()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.is()` along with `:empty` selector to achieve what you want.

Try,

```
$('#tblNodes > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('td').is(':empty')) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: what is difference between :empty and checking for ''? which one is good?

Comment: `:empty` will select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).  From the DOCs. And both methods are same..

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $('#tblNodes tr').each(function() {
   $td=$(this).find('td');
    if($td.text() == ''){
      $(this).hide();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#tblNodes > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('td').text() == ''){
    $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

1)Check for TD in each TR in table.

2)If it has no text , set its display property to none.

```
$('#tblNodes tr').each(function() {
   $td=$(this).find('td');
    if($td.text() === ''){
      $(this).css("display", "none");
    }
 });
```

Comment: this .hide is better or this.css.display none is better?

Comment: Both are same , hide(); set display property to none.But important to have info. about both .

Comment: If you want to go with little animation ,you can use  => hide("slow"); OR hide(1000);

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$('#tblNodes tbody  tr').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('td').is(':empty')) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```