# Hide table row if td is empty

Tags: html, jquery

I want to hide `tr` with class `cell` if `td` with class `emp` is empty. How to do it using jquery/javascript?

**Html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm" id="tblNodes">
   <thead>
      <tr class="text-center">
         <th class="col-3">Date</th>
         <th class="col-9">Employee</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-02</td>
         <td class="emp">
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-07</td>
         <td class="emp">
            <ul style="margin-bottom: 1px ">
               <li>Employee 1</li>
            </ul>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-09</td>
         <td class="emp">
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-13</td>
         <td class="emp">
            <ul style="margin-bottom: 1px ">
               <li>Employee 1</li>
            </ul>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-16</td>
         <td class="emp">
         </td>
      </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried something like code bellow, but still not working.

**Jquery**

```
$('#tblNodes > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
   if ($(this).find('td').is(':empty')) {
      $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery Hide table row if td has no text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292072/jquery-hide-table-row-if-td-has-no-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can iterate over each cell and check its `text` value. Then we hide its parent if the text is empty. We need to use `trim()` because jquery returns empty spaces and new lines sometimes for empty elements.

```js
$('#tblNodes td').each(function () {
   if ($(this).text().trim() === '') {
     $(this).parent().hide();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm" id="tblNodes">
   <thead>
      <tr class="text-center">
         <th class="col-3">Date</th>
         <th class="col-9">Employee</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-02</td>
         <td class="emp">
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-07</td>
         <td class="emp">
            <ul style="margin-bottom: 1px ">
               <li>Employee 1</li>
            </ul>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-09</td>
         <td class="emp">
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-13</td>
         <td class="emp">
            <ul style="margin-bottom: 1px ">
               <li>Employee 1</li>
            </ul>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-16</td>
         <td class="emp">
         </td>
      </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

What causes your code to not work are 2 things

first, you need to each directly through **td** instead of tr

secondly, i noticed from your code that you have a lot of white spaces here which will fail :empty test

[image]

```
$('#tblNodes > tbody td').each(function () {
   if ($(this).hasClass('emp') && $(this).is(':empty')) {
      $(this).parent().hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```js
$('#tblNodes > tbody td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html().trim() == '') {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm" id="tblNodes">
   <thead>
      <tr class="text-center">
         <th class="col-3">Date</th>
         <th class="col-9">Employee</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-02</td>
         <td class="emp">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-07</td>
         <td class="emp">
            <ul style="margin-bottom: 1px ">
               <li>Employee 1</li>
            </ul>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-09</td>
         <td class="emp">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-13</td>
         <td class="emp">
            <ul style="margin-bottom: 1px ">
               <li>Employee 1</li>
            </ul>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="cell">
         <td class="text-center range">2022-04-16</td>
         <td class="emp">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```